# Верификация открепленной цифровой подписи

Tags: cms, openssl

Есть два файла.

1. Оригинальный текстовый файл (filename.txt)
2. Файл цифровой подписи (filename.txt.sig)

Необходимо проверить: к этому ли файлу принадлежит эта подпись (этой ли подписью подписан этот файл), в общем убедиться, что файл оригинальный (не измененный) и подпись это подтверждает.

Формат подписи такой:

```
-----BEGIN CMS-----
закодировано base64 
-----END CMS-----
```

C помощью openssl посмотрел дамп этой подписи, скачал crt и crl файлы (url на которые нашёл в дампе), попробовал верифицировать файл с помощью командной строки openssl.

```
$ openssl cms -verify -content filename.txt -in filename.txt.sig -certfile cert.crt
unable to load certificates
```

Что я делаю не так? Как нужно делать правильно? Я в этом совершенно не понимаю пока ничего, но надеюсь с вашей помощью разобраться. Онлайн верификаторы сразу нет.

Comment: Может там гост?

Comment: Вероятно. Дамп показал это:
GOST R 34.11-2012 with 256 bit hash
Я пока слабо разбираюсь в этом вопросе.

Answer (score 0):

Нужно использовать движек для подписей по GOST.

Опенсорсный от Криптоком

- https://github.com/gost-engine/engine

Лицензионый от Криптопро

- https://cryptopro.ru/blog/2016/04/07/modul-gost-capi для старых openssl
- [gostengy](https://update.cryptopro.ru/support/nginx-gost/bin/) для новых openssl

Answer (score 0):

На WSL Debian я собрал openssl с gost-engine

```
$ openssl version -v
OpenSSL 1.1.1p  21 Jun 2022

$ openssl engine
(rdrand) Intel RDRAND engine
(dynamic) Dynamic engine loading support
(gost) Reference implementation of GOST engine

$ openssl ciphers | tr ':' '\n' | grep GOST
GOST2012-GOST8912-GOST8912
GOST2001-GOST89-GOST89
```

Пытаюсь проверить:

```
$ openssl smime -verify -noverify -in file.csv.sig -content file.csv -inform der
Error reading S/MIME message
140193840948480:error:0D0680A8:asn1 encoding routines:asn1_check_tlen:wrong tag:crypto/asn1/tasn_dec.c:1149:
140193840948480:error:0D07803A:asn1 encoding routines:asn1_item_embed_d2i:nested asn1 error:crypto/asn1/tasn_dec.c:309:Type=PKCS7

$ openssl cms -verify -noverify -in file.csv.sig -content file.csv -inform der
Error reading S/MIME message
140553009644800:error:0D0680A8:asn1 encoding routines:asn1_check_tlen:wrong tag:crypto/asn1/tasn_dec.c:1149:
140553009644800:error:0D07803A:asn1 encoding routines:asn1_item_embed_d2i:nested asn1 error:crypto/asn1/tasn_dec.c:309:Type=CMS_ContentInfo
```

Что-то делаю не так. А что не знаю. Как нужно правильно не знаю.

Comment: В текущем виде ваш ответ непонятен. Пожалуйста, нажмите [edit] под сообщением, чтобы добавить больше подробностей, которые помогут другим понять, как он отвечает на заданный вопрос. Вы можете найти больше информации о том, как писать хорошие ответы в [Справке](/help/how-to-answer).